# I want to search a text within a cell range and return the value to the left of the cell (Google App Script)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a script to organize a large quantity of data.

I am a newbie and would really need help in this:
[Sample Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A75K5.png)

It needs to find the word (e.g. Nike) from the range B2 to E3 and display the cell value left of the found cell under column I for Nike, same goes for columns J(Fila) and K(New Balance), please see attached screenshot.

I tried for with if then statement and i dont think i was doing it correctly at all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets Will guide you on using the information needed to edit/make Google App spreadsheets

So editing the values would just have to change the for loop for that.
Since you're wanting certain ranges, just change where the for loop starts.

```
for(int i = 0; i < /*data of spreadsheet*/; i++) {
    data[1][1] = B2
    data[1][2] = B3
}
```

Would be an example

```
data[1][1] = Shoes
data[1][2] = Nike/Fila/New Balance
data[2][1] = Pants
```

Comment: I will try this soon as i get in the ofc. Tnx!